# mouseenterr function not responding

Tags: jquery, html

My code works in JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gcubc2kn/, however I can't get it to work in notepad++. I'm not sure what the problem could be as I'm new to HTML in general.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">      </script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>

$('button').mouseenter(function () {    

$(this).html($(this).html() + '_');

});

$('button').mouseleave(function () {

var currentText = $(this).html

 $(this).html('about');
});
</script>

<style>
</style>

</head>

<body>
    <button id="button">about</button> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try using [$( document ).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: just write script inside in $( document ).ready(function() {
  //your code comes here
})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to attach to the mouseenter / mouseleave events of the button before the button actually exists.

Try moving your script to the bottom of the body.

Or attach to the events [when the document is ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/):

```
$(function() { // Shorthand for $( document ).ready()

    $('button').mouseenter(function () {    

    $(this).html($(this).html() + '_');

    });

    $('button').mouseleave(function () {

    var currentText = $(this).html

     $(this).html('about');
    });

});
```

Or attach to the document like this:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', 'button').mouseenter(function () {    

    $(this).html($(this).html() + '_');

});

$(document).on('mouseleave', 'button', function () {    

    var currentText = $(this).html

     $(this).html('about');
});
```

This way it doesn't matter if the element is created before or after you attach to the event.

Comment: Yes of course this make a lot of sense. I'm so used to C# where the order on the page of these sorts of things isn't important. Thank you